# WordPress custom image gallery linking to custom image size

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom image gallery shortcode that opens the images in a lightbox. The line that outputs the images is:

```
$image_output = "<a href='" . wp_get_attachment_url( $id )  . "' data-toggle='lightbox' data-gallery='$selector' data-footer='$attachment->post_excerpt'> " . wp_get_attachment_image($id, $atts['size'], false, $attr ) . "</a>";
```

Everything works great except this links to the original (and full size) image. I want it to instead link to a custom image size. I tried `wp_get_attachment_url( $id )` with `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'gallery-thumbnail', false )`.

However, instead of getting the desired image url I get `Array`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Should be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_get_attachment_image_src() returns an array (url, width, height) so use

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src(...)[0]
```

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_image_src($id)[0]` gives me the thumbnail but how do I get the `gallery-thumbnail` custom image size?

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'gallery-thumbnail' )[0]

Comment: Oops, I forgot the other parameters. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` takes the post_id and required size as parameters, and returns an array containing:

[0] = url
[1] = width
[2] = height
[3] = is_intermediate (i.e. whether it is a resized image or the original)

Therefore to get the url for a custom size called `gallery-thumbnail`, you need to do the following:

```
$img_attrib = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'gallery-thumbnail');
if ($img_attrib)
    $url = $img_attrib[0];
$image_output = "<a href='".$url."' [...rest of code...] </a>";
```

I've done it step-by-step so you can see what's happening but you can of course shorten this as follows - however this will have a broken link if the image can't be found.

```
<a href='".wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'gallery-thumbnail')[0]."' [...rest of code...] </a>"
```

Note: This assumes you have defined your custom size in functions.php using `add_image_size` and regenerated your thumbnails so that version of all images has been created.

**Ref:** [Developer Reference for wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer but @B68C beat you to it. I like your fallback though!

Comment: @TroyTempleman Yeah I'd seen your question but I'd to go offline before I finished and B68C had answered when I came back to finish. Its a good idea for custom sizes to use a default size as a fallback - I didn't include the full implementation here but you get the idea. Glad you found the answer anyway :)